# How am I supposed to prove that this fraction is irrational?

Tags: calculus, fractions, irrational-numbers

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{1+\sqrt[3]2}\notin\Bbb Q.$$

I have proved that both numbers are irrational but I don't think that is sufficient to prove that the fraction is irrational

Comment: I think you can argue by contradiction: if $\frac{\sqrt 2}{1+ 2^{1/3}} = p\in \mathbb Q$,  after some calculation you show $\sqrt 2$ is rational.

Comment: You are right that the argument that both numbers are irrational is not sufficient.

Comment: @ArcticChar Not at all obvious how we should arrive at $\sqrt{2}$ , how do you get rid of the third root ?

Comment: I guess I would isolate $2^{1/3}$ on one side and take $(\cdot)^3$ on both sides. @Peter

Comment: OK, this could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt[3]{2}}\in \mathbb{Q} $ then $p^2 =\frac{2}{1+2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and also $\frac{2}{p^2}-1=2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\in\mathbb{Q}$ but then $\left(\frac{2}{p^2}-1\right)^2=4\sqrt[3]{4}+8 +2\sqrt[3]2 \in\mathbb{Q}$ and then $$\sqrt[3]{4}=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{p^2}-1\right)^2-\left(\frac{2}{p^2}-1\right) -8}{3}\in \mathbb{Q}$$

but the last is impossible.